# How can I find an element of a particular type in a list, and also smart cast the result?

Tags: list, kotlin, types

Suppose I have a `List<Animal>`, and I want to find the first `Dog` in it. I then want to access some `Dog`-specific properties of the found `Dog`.

`find` doesn't really work:

```
val dog = animals.find { it is Dog }
// dog is of type "Animal?", but I want "Dog?"
```

I could use `filterIsInstance`:

```
val dog = animals.filterIsInstance<Dog>().firstOrNull()
```

But that goes through the whole animal list. I want it to stop when it finds the first dog. What is a built in method that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sequences for lazy evaluations

Compare following code samples:

**Eager**

```kotlin
val firstString = listOf(1, "2", 3, "4", 5, "6")
        // following operations are applied to List
        .filterIsInstance<String>()
        .onEach { println(it) }
        .firstOrNull()

println("Result: $firstString")
```

Output:

```
2
4
6
Result: 2
```

**Lazy**

```kotlin
val firstString = listOf(1, "2", 3, "4", 5, "6")
        .asSequence()
        // following operations are applied to Sequence
        .filterIsInstance<String>()
        .onEach { println(it) }
        .firstOrNull()

println("Result: $firstString")
```

Output:

```
2
Result: 2
```

In both cases result is the same, but for lazy case no further steps are made after first match is found.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`firstNotNullOfOrNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first-not-null-of-or-null.html) (which is a mouthful to say :D), with `as?` instead of `is`.

```
val dog = animals.firstNotNullOfOrNull { it as? Dog }
```

It applies the transformation to each element, and returns the first not-null transformation result, or null if there is no such result.

There is also the counterpart `firstNotNullOf` that throws an exception when there are no not-null results.